# Is it possible to count the number of duplicates from two column by using single hash?

Tags: perl, hash

My input data as follow. From below data I want to unique the `p1 p2 .. p5` and the first column and get the count of those.

```
ID  M   N 
cc1 1   p1
cc1 10  p2
cc1 10  p2
cc2 1   p1
cc2 2   p5
cc3 2   p1
cc3 2   p4
```

I expected the result was

```
ID  M   p1  p2  p3  p4  p5 
cc1 3   1   2   0   0   0   
cc3 2   1   0   0   1   0   
cc2 2   1   0   0   0   1
```

For this I tried the `hash of hash` and `hash` I'm getting output what I expect. But my doubt is it is possible to do this by using single hash.? Because the same data was stored into the two different hash.

```
my (%hash,$hash2);
<$fh>;
while (<$fh>)
{
    my($first,$second,$thrid) = split("\t");
    $hash{$first}{$thrid}++; #I tried $hash{$first}++{$thrid}++ It throws syntax error
    $hash2{$first}++; #it is possible to reduce this hash
}
my @ar = qw(p1  p2  p3  p4  p5);
$, = "\t"; 
print @ar,"\n";
foreach (keys %hash)
{
    print "$_\t$hash2{$_}\t";
    foreach my $ary(@ar)
    {
        if(!$hash{$_}{$ary})
        {
            print "0\t"; 
        }
        else
        {
            print "$hash{$_}{$ary}\t";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the last line of your output. Why do `p4` and `p5` have values of 4 and 1? There is no line in the input with `10_Coverage_Contigs_contig_3` and an SSR of `p5`

Comment: @Borodin Sorry one small typo post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use 2 hashes. you can use only hash of hash. I've just modified your code. see that below code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
<DATA>;
while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my($first,$second,$thrid) = split("\t");
    $hash{$first}{$thrid}++; #I tried $hash{$first}++{$thrid}++ It throws syntax error
}
my @ar = qw(p1  p2  p3  p4  p5);
$, = "\t"; 
print @ar,"\n";
foreach (keys %hash)
{
#    print "$_\t$hash2{$_}\t";
    my @in = values $hash{$_};
    my $cnt = eval(join("+",@in));
    print "$_\t$cnt\t";
    foreach my $ary(@ar)
    {
        if(!$hash{$_}{$ary})
        {
            print "0\t"; 
        }
        else
        {
            print "$hash{$_}{$ary}\t";
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

You have hash of hash to store data. first keys are `id` and second keys are `N`. Simply count values of the `id`, it gives the total values what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %count_of;

#read the header row 
chomp( my @header = split ' ', <DATA> );

while (<DATA>) {
   my ( $ID, $M, $N ) = split;
   $count_of{ $ID }{ $N }++;
}
#print Dumper \%count_of;

#setup the output headers. We could autodetect, but some of these (p3) are entirely empty. 
my @p_headers = qw ( p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 );
#if you did want to:
#my @p_headers = sort keys %{{map { $_ => 1 } map { keys %{$count_of{$_}} } keys %count_of }};
#will give p1 p2 p4 p5. 

print join "\t", qw ( ID M ), @p_headers, "\n";
foreach my $ID ( sort keys %count_of ) {
   my $total = 0;
   $total += $_ for values %{ $count_of{$ID} };
   print join "\t", 
                   $ID, 
                   $total,
                   ( map { $count_of{$ID}{$_} // 0 } @p_headers ),
                   "\n";
}

__DATA__
ID  M   N 
cc1 1   p1
cc1 10  p2
cc1 10  p2
cc2 1   p1
cc2 2   p5
cc3 2   p1
cc3 2   p4
```